# Resource not found Exception Gridview Adapter

Tags: android, gridview

This code run well in another project but when i populate this GridView in another project i get resource does not found i put every drawables all Xml
please help me to solve this query.thanks
GridView Adapter:

```
     @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Holder holder=new Holder();
            View rowView;

            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_category_list, null);
            holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
// crasher here.
            holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
            holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

            rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+result[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            return rowView;
            }
```

ListviewActivity :

```
GridView gv;
    Context context;
    ArrayList prgmName;
    public static String [] categorylist ={"Cleaner","Mechanic","Plumber","Carpenter"};
    public static int [] prgmImages={R.drawable.cleaning,R.drawable.mechanic,R.drawable.plumber,R.drawable.carpenter};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);
        gv=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        gv.setAdapter(new Adapter_Category_list(this, categorylist,prgmImages));
```

Error :

[image]

Comment: i populate correct gridview item and pass images id how ever compiler does not found :(

Comment: just check what imageId[position] returns

Comment: it returns 2130837595 @Gautam